# Autosaving data using LokiJS and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, lokijs

I am facing some difficulty in finding the perfect solution of autosaving data while using LokiJS in NodeJS...

I tried something from the official doc, but all it says is that saveDB is not a function.

Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize a new database you can specify the `autosave` and `autoload` parameters:

```
let db = new loki('db.json', {autosave: true, autoload: true});
```

You can also manually save after you make any changes with:

```
db.saveDatabase();
```

Comment: What's the use of Persistence Adapters then?

Comment: Will the above written code autosave the data at regular intervals?

Comment: Yes, but you can also specify the interval with the `autosaveInterval` parameter (in milliseconds).

Comment: The purpose of persistence adaptors is to provide alternate (and custom) methods of storage: filesystem, localstorage (browser).  If you do not specify a system it will detect a default adaptor based on your environment (filesystem for node and localstorage for browser & cordova).